# Why isn't this Ruby syntax error detected?

Tags: ruby, syntax-error, rubocop

The following code has invalid syntax:

```
# bad_code.rb
def foo
  next
end

$ ruby bad_code.rb 
bad_code.rb:2: Invalid next
bad_code.rb: compile error (SyntaxError)
```

However, running `ruby -c bad_code.rb` doesn't detect any problems:

```
$ ruby -c bad_code.rb 
Syntax OK
```

Yet `ruby -c` is supposed to be for checking syntax:

> -c              check syntax only

Why isn't it detecting this error?

`rubocop bad_code.rb` also doesn't detect this:

```
$ rubocop bad_code.rb 
Inspecting 1 file
.

1 file inspected, no offenses detected
```

I ran this on Ruby 2.1.10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is syntactically correct, but when the ruby interpreter tries to produce code for it, it recognizes that there is no target for the `next`